# How to change the bgcolor of td

Tags: html, html-table, sugarcrm

I have a recurring table rows:

```
<h3>{sugarCRM_translate label='LBL_RPT_GROUP_BY_EMPLOYEES' module='Opportunities'}</h3>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="list view gird" width="100%">
<tr>
    <th width="13%">{sugarCRM_translate label='LBL_LIST_NAME' module='Employees'}</td>
    <th width="7%">{sugarCRM_translate label='LBL_LIST_DEPARTMENT' module='Employees'}</td>
    <th scope="col">{sugarCRM_translate label='LBL_MONTHLY_TARGET' module='Opportunities'}</th>
    <th scope="col">{$labelActual}</th>
    <th scope="col">{sugarCRM_translate label='LBL_RPT_COMPLETED_PERCENT' module='Opportunities'}</th>
    <th scope="col">{$labelMissing}</th>
</tr>
{counter start=0 name="rowCounter" print=false assign="rowCounter"}
{foreach name=rowEmpl from=$employees key=id item=row}
    {if $smarty.foreach.rowEmpl.iteration is odd}
        {assign var='_rowColor' value=$rowColor[0]}
    {else}
        {assign var='_rowColor' value=$rowColor[1]}
    {/if}
    {counter name="rowCounter"}
<tr class="{$_rowColor}S1">
    <td>{$row.name}</td>
    <td>{$row.department}</td>
    <td align="right">{$row.MonthlyTarget|format_number}</td>
    <td align="right">{$row.ActualAmount|format_number}</td>
    <td align="center">{$row.PercentTarget}%</td>
    <td align="right">{$row.MissingAmount|format_number}</td>
</tr>
{/foreach}
</table>
```

**My problem:** 
I need to change the `bgcolor` of in which contains `MissingAmount` is Red when `$row.MissingAmount >=0` and it's Blue when `$row.MissingAmount < 0`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use Document Object Model (DOM)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be helpful try this

```
<td align="right" if({$row.MissingAmount0}>0){style="background: blue"} elseif({$row.MissingAmount}<0){style="background: red"} >{$row.MissingAmount|format_number}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it:

```
{counter start=0 name="rowCounter" print=false assign="rowCounter"}
{foreach name=rowEmpl from=$employees key=id item=row}
    {if $smarty.foreach.rowEmpl.iteration is odd}
        {assign var='_rowColor' value=$rowColor[0]}
    {else}
        {assign var='_rowColor' value=$rowColor[1]}
    {/if}
    {if $row.MissingAmount >= 0}
        {assign var='_Color' value="green"}
    {else}
        {assign var='_Color' value="red"}
    {/if}
    {counter name="rowCounter"}
<tr class="{$_rowColor}S1">
    <td>{$row.name}</td>
    <td>{$row.department}</td>
    <td align="right">{$row.MonthlyTarget|format_number}</td>
    <td align="right">{$row.ActualAmount|format_number}</td>
    <td align="center">{$row.PercentTarget}%</td>
    <td style="color:{$_Color}" align="right">{$row.MissingAmount|format_number}</td>
</tr>
{/foreach}
```